# Probability of coins

Tags: probability

[image]

How do we do question 4? I tried putting "non of the above" and "all 3 equally likely". They were wrong.

Comment: Indeed they are.  Hint: What is the probability of {all six heads}?  How does it compare to {4 heads and 2 tails}?  Notice: that is not {4 heads *then* 2 tails}.

Comment: it is 1/64. but ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the second option.

Does your intuition really tell you that all three are equally likely? What do you think is more likely when flipping a fair coin $100$ times; $100$ heads or around $50$ heads and $50$ tails? Why?

Think about these questions and try to work out the probability for each of the three cases (remember that order doesn't matter). If you are still in doubt after this, let me know and I'll expand my answer to include some calculations.

Comment: A doubt. If the order did matter, is it right to say all of them did have the same probability?

Comment: @RStyle Only if you can tell the coins apart!

Comment: Why is that a doubt.  It specifically says "in any order".

Comment: Yea just wondering. So its more likely to have 3 heads 3 tails

Comment: @RStyle Yes, but do you understand why? Can you calculate the probabilities for each scenario?

Comment: Indeed.  Have you studied the *[binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)* yet? @RStyle